# NSAutoreleasePool is unavailable

Tags: objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

I am following "Programming in Objective-C" 3<sup>rd</sup> edition and I am having problems with the first example.

I keep getting this error:

> Semantic Issue: 'NSAutoreleasePool' is unavailable: not available in
>   automatic reference counting mode

Here is my code:

```
//
// main.m
// prog1 //
// Created by Steve Kochan on 1/30/11.
// Copyright 2011 ClassroomM, Inc.. All rights reserved. //

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog (@"Programming is fun!");
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see if you can read your own question - code needs to be marked as code

Comment: Isn't the Lion preview under NDA?

Comment: You cannot ask this question here yet because the Lion SDK is under NDA.

Comment: ARC is not under NDA, though Lion & iOS 5 are.

Comment: Sorry mark, I was not familiar with the StackOverflow formatting

Comment: @Greg, try asking questions like this over at [http://devforums.apple.com/](http://devforums.apple.com/).

Comment: Nope;  this very much is a real question and can be answered here.  Carefully.  Edited question to no longer have any NDA'd goop.

Answer (score 42):

The compiler is being asked to compile the file with ARC (automatic reference counting) enabled.  Turn that off or, better yet, modernize your example:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog (@"Programming is fun!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(No, I can't tell you how, specifically, to turn off ARC, if that was the route you were to go down due to the aforementioned NDA.)

Comment: Your comment "modernize your example" has me worried-- I too am starting the same book mentioned in the original question, if the very first example in the book is doing something "out dated" is it even worth continuing or should I look for a new book?

Comment: The knowledge is still applicable.  Even with ARC, it is still useful to understand the details of manual retain/release.   Heck, even if you only ever intend to write an iOS app, you'll still benefit from knowing other languages.   But, yes, the book documents patterns that are no longer the most modern.

Comment: @bbum On releasing there is a similar problem. How will you 'modernise':  self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
Apologies if this is simple, but I'm just using XCode for a PhoneGap project, so don't know much about Objective C memory management

Answer (score 19):

Quick post just in case you still looking

You can disable ARC in build settings.

- Click on you project, in the left hand organizer.
- Select your target, in the next column over.
- Select the *Build Settings* tab at the top.
- Scroll down to "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" (it may be 
  listed as "CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC" under the *User-Defined* settings 
  group), (if you do not find ARC option under build settings, you might need 
  to toggle you compiler. You can find it under build settings)
- and set it to NO.

Comment: This fixed it for me on OS X Lion - Thanks Jason!

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I wanted ARC on, and wanted to update a sample project to work properly. Apple's NSAutoReleasePool docs are technically correct, but don't come straight out and explain this. Here's how:

Take your application main, which probably looks something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([DemoAppDelegate class]));

    [pool release];

    return retVal;
}
```

And change it to look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([DemoAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226) to Apple's transition guide to ARC.

OK...check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAutoreleasePool) out. Specific change to NSAutoreleasePool - this is how Xcode initializes itself when you create your first app. I don't know about you, but I love this idea!

No worries if you are following along w/ Kochan's book. When starting your project, just uncheck the "Use ARC" box. Everything will work.

Answer (score -1):

ARC is enabled when you first create a new project. Right know the only way I know how to enable or not enable it is when you first create your program. It is one of the checkboxes you have to unselect.

Comment: Is @JasonRogers' answer wrong where he tells how to tuen ARC off?