# Received memory warning Phonegap application Crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing phonegap application for iPad using jQuery mobile.
My application crash when receive this message "Received memory warning"..

Please help me.?

Thank you

I am using phonegap(cordova-1.6.0) , jQuery mobile 1.6.4 and IOS 5.1

Comment: You aren't giving us much to go on.

Comment: Are you doing anything excessive with the dom? Like do you have 1000 listview items. Or perhaps a huge multi-page JQM document.

Comment: @codaniel   No. But my sqlite database is pre populated database and which  has more than 4000 thousand records.

Comment: Oh I think there is a limit. Do you know how much is in there?

Comment: Like how many megabytes we talking here.

Comment: Hmm I think the limit is 5mb. Anything else abnormal? Like how big is your index.html?

Comment: index.html is 6 kb . Is there way  to increase database limit?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Actually this issue is not phonegap. I used iPad 1. I think its iPad1 issues.When i test in iPad 2 and iPad3 that not displayed.

Comment: Because your iPad has comparatively more memory size.

Answer (score 1):

Switch the phone off and back on again. Then run via Xcode again, and see if the message is gone. If it's gone, then you or the phonegap libs probably locked up some memory.

Comment: I have tried this and this was fixed.. But after sometime it displays again Received memeory warning.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of Xcode, and then check if you are getting LLVM related warning messages (click the triangle toolbar button with the exclamation mark in it). If you do, it should give you and option to automaticcally apply fixes. After doing this, mine seems fine, but I can't guarantee it will be a fix.

Comment: By default Xcode uses the "Apple LLVM" compiler, but PhoneGap uses "LLVM GCC". One of the differences between them is the way they do memory management. I'm not an expert in this, so you'll have to read about it, or play with your Build Settings. Keep an eye on warnings - they are there for a reason ;-)

Comment: Hi, as a last note, follow the advice given here to get rid of warnings. You should still use the "Apple LLVM" compiler, but should turn of automatic reference counting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006593/ipad-testing-of-phonegap-application-issues-in-main-method

Comment: If an app is exited, all memory associated with that app will be released to the system (barring an OS bugs which is exceedingly rare).

Answer (score 0):

Because the ipad 1 has no the same performance as the ipad 2 and 3 ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue will still reside with your Application, the only reason it will work on the iPad 2 and 3 is because they have more memory.

I would suggest you look into Memory Management within your wrapper as you cannot rely on hardware to cover up flaws in software - as if you continue down the track it will only get worse.

- This was posted to avoid incoming traffic being shown an incorrect, correct answer.

Answer (score -4):

"Received memory warning" means that you are using too much memory.

To fix this, you should modify your program to use less memory.

---

Yes, this answer was somewhat facetious.  However, without any code, any architectural information, any user interface information, or any other details, this about as good of an answer as you will get.

Comment: There are any tool to view memory leak?

Comment: Haha now why couldn't I think of that answer?

Comment: @codaniel I am using Javascripts. How can I modify my program to use less memory.

Comment: It's a shame I don't have permission for downvoting