# Why am I seeing a message warning about NSAutoreleasePool being unavailable?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Any idea why I get these messages:

> NSAutoreleasePool is unavailable: not available in automatic reference
>   counting mode
>
> ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'

in this code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655842/nsautoreleasepool-is-unavailable

Answer (score 7):

This is because you are compiling with Automatic Reference Counting on. You need to use a different construct with ARC:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    // Your code
}
```

Another option is to [turn off ARC for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project).

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, you have Automatic Reference Counting enabled, which doesn't allow you to explicitly use 'release'. You need to either disable ARC or change your main method to look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Under targets->Build settings->Apple LLVM Complailer 3.0

Objective-C Garbage Collection  (change to ) Supported [ -fobjc-gc]